# Can GPX Files Contain More Than 1 Track?

Tags: gpx

Question: can GPX files contain more than 1 track?  I am new to using this format.  Since you can name a track, it suggested to me that I could put multiple tracks in a file.  However, when I tried testing the file out (for exampe, on http://www.mygpsfiles.com/app/), it only displays one of the tracks.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the .gpx file format will hold individual features that your gps unit will display as separate tracks. I don't think you can save separate tracks into a single file on a handheld gps unit - you have to do it on a desktop program. I've never tried the website you've linked to; if you can post your data, or describe how you created your .gpx file, someone might be able to troubleshoot your specific problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. As noted above, most handheld ones generate a single track. But if you combine GPX tracks (using some software or programming language) into a single file, they will have a new GPX tag delineating which track is which. For example, if you combine GPX files with common market software, the new combined GPX file will have a tag called `<trkseg>` to denote which track is which. Because GPX is based on XML, and XML is incredibly flexible, there may be other tags that show if there are multiple tracks in a single GPX file.